# Latest version of Firefox won't start in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, firefox

Since yesterday Firefox won't start when I click on the icon.
I'm running Linux Mint 14 in VirtualBox. I think it's trying to update to version 39.0.3.
In a terminal I get
firefox -safe-mode
Error: Platform version '39.0.3' is not compatible with
minVersion >= 39.0
maxVersion <= 39.0
Is there something I can do (update a configuration file?) to make this work?
Thanks for any help

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for the Superuser exchange. http://superuser.com

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Your comment is still very helpful in 2018. And it also looks beautiful when rendered in magenta and cyan in the lynx browser^^ Thanks for the reminder.